# VNC to Linux from MAC OSx up/down arrow keys not working

Tags: linux, macos, vnc

up/down array keys are not being sent to VNC from my MAC OS. left/right arrow keys are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Ubuntu settings, go to hardware/keyboard. Open up the keyboard icon. It will contain Shortcuts. Disable shortcuts under the section Windows... there is a super up and super down. disable then and the arrow keys will map to either usual role.